# Single liner to add text to filename before extension with f-strings

Tags: python, f-string

I want to add some text to a file name before the extension. Example: `name.ext` >>> `name_su.ext`.
I can do it with traditional python string formatting:

```
filename = 'name.ext'
suffix = '_su'
print("{0}{2}{1}".format(*os.path.splitext(filename) + (suffix, )))
# This will print: name_su.ext
```

I wonder if I can achieve the same with f-string notation, in a single line, without calling `os.path.splitext(filename)` twice.

Comment: FWIW, you don't even need interpolation for this. `suffix.join(os.path.splitext(filename))`

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756537/f-string-syntax-for-unpacking-a-list-with-brace-suppression) question.

Comment: @wjandrea, thanks A LOT for this advice. It's quite obvious but I never would have thought about it, and I used it today for this same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `os.path.splitext()` twice might be avoidable, but it's fast and readable:

```py
print(f'{os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + suffix + os.path.splitext(filename)[1]}')
```

Comment: Thank you, @AlexM. I was looking for a way to do it without calling twice `os.path.splitext()`.

Comment: Why even bother with an f-string? `print(os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + suffix + os.path.splitext(filename)[1])`

Comment: Also, there's no need to call it twice, like I commented on the question: `suffix.join(os.path.splitext(filename))`. So if you needed an f-string, `print(f'{suffix.join(os.path.splitext(filename))}')`