# Tuple unpacking to formatted string in Python

Tags: python, string, tuples, string-formatting, iterable-unpacking

I have been working though *Fluent Python 2nd Edition* by *Luciano Ramalho*.

On page 5 he writes that he has attempted to adopt the **f string** syntax throughout the book, although there are times when **str.format()** is better.

However in the below example he uses the **`%`** format to unpack a tuple:

```py
traveler_ids = [('USA', '31195855'), ('BRA', 'CE342567'), ('ESP', 'XDA205856')]

# % operator
for passport in sorted(traveler_ids):
    print('%s/%s' % passport)
```

I managed to unpack the same tuple using the other two formatting methods, although the f string uses a **`,`** rather than a **`/`**. I got this f string solution from [[SenhorLucas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756537/f-string-syntax-for-unpacking-a-list-with-brace-suppression)], using a comma to seperate however this is perhaps not as clear as the slash:

```py
# str.format()
for passport in sorted(traveler_ids):
    print('{}/{}'.format(*passport))

# f string
for passport in sorted(traveler_ids):
    print(f'{*passport,}')
```

---

## Questions

1. First I was wondering, what is clearer in this case? Is there a difference in performance when using `*passport`?
2. Secondly, is there a simple way to unpack using the same **/** divider in an f string?

Comment: Does this help `print('/'.join(passport))`?

Comment: @toyotaSupra that is a handy solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could unpack during enumeration of the sorted list which then makes f-string usage more straightforward :

```
traveler_ids = [('USA', '31195855'), ('BRA', 'CE342567'), ('ESP', 'XDA205856')]

for country, passport_number in sorted(traveler_ids):
    print(f"{country}/{passport_number}")

# or, avoiding f-string and join (not a recommendation)...

for country, passport_number in sorted(traveler_ids):
    print(country, passport_number, sep="/")
```